# spring/hibernate: open/close session each time VS getCurrentSession

Tags: spring, hibernate, session

What are the differences between these approaches and which one is better? Until now I'm having pieces of code like the following:

```
public void delete(Song song) {
    session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.delete(song);
    session.flush();
}
```

but the record is not always deleted when above code is run (precisely: id=1 is never deleted and other ids are deleted always). I read that keeping opened session speeds up the application a little bit - that's why I'm sharing the session object. My business object get the session factory via DI:

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

Session session = null;

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my expereince with Hibernate, I came to the conclusion that the best strategy is to match the Hibernate session life span with the duration of a single transaction. Based on your specific needs, you might have to do something else, but I bet the proposed startegy would work in 95% of practical cases.